# cakephp emailers duplicating email component issue

Tags: cakephp-1.2

I am using cakephp 1.2.8 To schedule newsletters we are using email component and set the URL in cron job.

The issue we facing is, its sending emails multiple times. We have checked in logs and cron. No issue in cron as well as code. How to identify the issue ? Is there issue in cake 1.2 ??

Answer (score 0):

You may use a separate table to store pending emails. Check the table each time before sending emails. Once the email has been sent, delete the emails from the table. It may resolve your issue.